# The connection has failed while creating a New Repository using Oracle BI 11g Administration Tool

Tags: dns, connection, repository, business-intelligence

In the BI Administration Tool when I try to create a `New Repository` faced

> The connection has failed

I try all of these solutions but didnt work:

1. configured my `System DSN`
2. enter “TNS_ADMIN” for the `Variable Name` field and for the `Variable Value` enter the location of my OBIEE
3. copy the sqlnet and tnsnames.ora files into `E:\obiee11gtmt\Oracle_BI1\network\admin` and `E:\obiee11gtmt\oracle_common\network\admin`.
4. put this in DSN with connection type OCI 10g/11g

   ```
   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = IP Addr)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) ))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I resolved it by correctly setting TNS_ADMIN environment variable [user.cmd/ user.sh depends upon OS].

Step 1:
Place tnsnames.ora file in both directory.

E:\obiee11gtmt\Oracle_BI1\network\admin

E:\obiee11gtmt\oracle_common\network\admin

Step 2:

Setting environment variable in configuration file [user.cmd]

Path: 
E:\obiee11gtmt\instances\instance1\bifoundation\OracleBIApplication\coreapplication\setup

[user.cmd/ user.sh depends upon OS]

@echo off

REM This file is a placeholder for setting environment variables

REM set TNS_ADMIN=E:\obiee11gtmt\Oracle_BI1\network\admin

Reference: http://123obi.com/2011/03/error-the-connection-has-failed-in-obiee-11g/